# ServerAuthenticationStateProvider reports Win32Exception: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor

I have a blazor server app with one page

## Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<AuthorizeView Roles="sample_role">
    You see this because you have the sample_role
</AuthorizeView>

<p>Everyone sees this</p>
```

Since `sample_role` does not exist in any Default Active Directory, I wrote a custom authentication provider to inject that role based on a database of existing users.

```
public class CustomAuth : ServerAutheticationProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var state = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        var currentUserId = state.User.Identity.Name;     
        // now I fetch permissions for this user from a database

        bool userHasRole = Database.DoesRoleExistFor(currentUserId);

        if(userHasRole) {
           var sample_role = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "sample_role");
           var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { sample_role });
           state.User.AddIdentity(identity);

          
           NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.From(new AutheticationState(state.User)));
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

I configured this class to be the default `AuthenticationStateProvider` in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuth>();
```

All of the above works on my development machine where my machine is joined to a domain. The value for `currentUserId` is something like `DOMAIN\USERNAME`.

This code also works on my personal machine which is not part of any domain. The value for `currentUserId` in that case is `COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME`.

However, when I move my code to a production environment, with a different domain name, I get an exception:

> Win32Exception: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.

When I change the line:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="sample_role">
```

To

```
<AuthorizeView>
```

The code works, but I lose the ability to decide who gets to see what.

How can I solve this issue?